# Xamarin.Forms portable project as NuGet package

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package

I tried creating a Xamarin.Forms portable project as a Nuget package, but I am having some problems with iOS
One of the errors are

```
Failed to add reference. The package 'Xamarin.Essentials' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Drawing.Common.dll' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
```

What can be wrong? 
Or is it simply not possible?

**UPDATE**

I have tried reinstalling Xamarin.Essential without success.

I tried adding the `<DisableExtraReferences>true</DisableExtraReferences>` to csproj like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DisableExtraReferences>true</DisableExtraReferences>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

But now it comes with this error when trying to get it from NuGet

```
Package is not found in the following primary source(s): <path to Azure Nuget>. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
```

When I try downloading a previous version it fails with the 1st error.

I also tried installing `Xamarin.Build.Download`, but that did not work either

Comment: Do any of the suggestions in [this discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/178982/has-anyone-seen-an-error-while-updating-xamarin-essentials-1-3-1-to-1-4-0) help?

Comment: Also there is an [open bug](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7249) in which a workaround is suggested:  "Also try this in your project: `<DisableExtraReferences>true</DisableExtraReferences>`".

Comment: No, it comes with the same error :(

Comment: Sorry mate, beyond my expertise then.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am testing it right now. But the 1st thing did not help, right now Azure is building for 2nd time ;)